# In Orbeon Forms 4.8.0, in a component, is $class supposed to contain a class like fr-grid-1?

Tags: orbeon

When I was using Orbeon Forms 4.7.0, I developed a custom map component. It contained the following logic:

```
<xh:div class="fb-area-of-interest-cwm-map-div{if ($class = '')
            then ' fb-area-of-interest-cwm-map-div-default'
            else concat(' ', $class)}" id="map_div" xbl:attr="style"/>
```

The `fb-area-of-interest-cwm-map-div-default` class had the default style (including size) of the map.  The idea was that if the user then edited the Control Settings in Form Builder and added Custom CSS classes then the $class value would no longer be empty and the Custom CSS class would be used instead of my default. I got the idea from looking at code for the existing map component.

I think that I may have misunderstood how the $class variable is meant to be used. When I upgraded to Orbeon 4.8.0, this logic no longer worked because $class now contains a class like `fr-grid-1` if the component is used in Form Runner.

As an alternative, I can just change the logic to:

```
<xh:div class="fb-area-of-interest-cwm-map-div
               fb-area-of-interest-cwm-map-div-default{if ($class = '')
               then ''
               else concat(' ', $class)}" id="map_div" xbl:attr="style"/>
```

The Custom CSS class specified in Form Builder takes precedence since I am declaring it in a `<xh:style type="text/css">` in the `<xh:head>` of the form source.

This works fine in Form Runner, but unfortunately in Form Builder the Custom CSS class has no effect. In general, CSS classes in `<xh:head><xh:style type="text/css">` don't seem to have any effect in Form  Builder.

1. Did I misunderstand how the $class variable is meant to be used?
2. Is there a better alternative?
3. Why doesn't the Custom CSS class have an effect in Form Builder?

Comment: Where does that `$class` come from? AFAIK, there is no `$class` automatically put in scope for you, so that must be something you are declaring your own XBL control, isn't it?
About the <xh:head><xh:style type="text/css"> not being taken into account in Form Builder, indeed, it should. I created an issue for that: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2126

Comment: Ah, you're right. It is declared as: `<xf:var name="class" xbl:attr="xbl:text=class"/>`

Comment: OK, does that answer your question on where `$class` comes from? You're saying that its value is `fr-grid-1`, but you're not saying if you expected a different value, and in the case which one, and why?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was expecting that if a value was entered in the "Custom CSS classes" field in FB, then `$class` would contain only that value and if not, then `$class` would be empty. Behaviour of 4.7.0 supported that, but 4.8.0 has the `fr-grid-1` value. I think I just made a false assumption, that's all.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to check the value of "Custom CSS classes", since this way seems to be wrong.

Comment: I'm not following; what do you mean by "check the value of Custom CSS classes"?

Comment: In FB, if you open Control Settings for a control, there is a field called "Custom CSS classes". I was trying to figure out if there was a way for my XBL component to perform some logic based on the value entered in that field. Like the logic at the beginning of my question.

Comment: `xxf:avt-value('id-of-element', 'class')` should work for elements in the same xBL scope. I don't know if that's the case for you. But this allows you to get the value of an AVT.